# Can Powerbuilder Graph labels show values instead of percentages?

Tags: graph, powerbuilder

Using PB 12

I have a pie chart that breaks down project billings.  It is showing percentages, but for me it would be more useful to show the values.

I am having a very hard time finding any resources on manipulating charts.  I'd also like to be able to put more information into the legend, but again, not finding any guides to this.

Any help greatly appreciated,
Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the values instead of percentages :

- Edit the datawindow, select the "Text" tab
- Select "Pie Graph Labels" in the TextObject drop-down list
- In the "Display Expression" field  type "value"

I'm using PB10.5, I hope it's same with 12.